# Batch class condition

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

I need to write a batch class. I need to create case when below condition is satisfied. If(**Feedback Submitted Date** == NULL AND **Due Date** is expired on the Schedule job running date). Here highlighted fields are date field.

How to add this condition in batch class? how to compare date field with Schedule job running date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the relevant code or whatever you have done to achieve this

Comment: Please explain with more details

Comment: Requirement: Cases should  be created for each 'Feedback Service Case Data' record that meets the below criteria, 

If(Feedback Submitted Date == NULL AND

Due Date is expired on the Schedule job running date)

Comment: Feedback Service Case Data is object

Comment: In batch class.

Comment: So you have not tried anything. You want the community to give you code to meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Since the scheduled job run date is by definition TODAY, the query for the start method is simply:

```
[select id, ... FROM Foo__c
     WHERE Feedback_Submitted_Date__c = null AND
           Due_Date__c = TODAY]  // use special date filters
```